# How to return the permalink in WordPress REST API with ACF?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF + the ACF to REST API plugin.

I have a global options page with a field that links to a post (this is an ACF post relationship field).

If I navigate to: `/wp-json/acf/v3/options/options`

The response looks like this:

```
{
  "acf": {
    "sticker_button": {
      "title": "Come & visit",
      "post_object": {
        "ID": 311,
        "post_author": "2",
        "post_date": "2019-04-30 18:39:50",
        "post_date_gmt": "2019-04-30 17:39:50",
        "post_content": "",
        "post_title": "test",
        "post_excerpt": "",
        "post_status": "publish",
        "comment_status": "closed",
        "ping_status": "closed",
        "post_password": "",
        "post_name": "test",
        "to_ping": "",
        "pinged": "",
        "post_modified": "2019-04-30 18:39:50",
        "post_modified_gmt": "2019-04-30 17:39:50",
        "post_content_filtered": "",
        "post_parent": 97,
        "guid": "https://example.dev.env.example.com/?page_id=311",
        "menu_order": 0,
        "post_type": "page",
        "post_mime_type": "",
        "comment_count": "0",
        "filter": "raw"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Because I am using an SPA to consume this data, I do not want to make another API request simply to get this posts permalink/link.

Is there a way to display the permalink in the response of the said post along with the `post_object`?

Simply using `post_name` to build a link manually is not enough, because it could be a sub-page of another. I need the actual permalink at runtime and the `post_name` is not affected by page hierarchy.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the ACF to Rest plugin has a list of WP filters you can tap into for various types of WP REST Routes responses (see [here](https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api#filters)).

My suggestion would be to use the `acf/rest_api/{type}/prepare_item` filter if you'd like to alter the response for individual response item OR the `acf/rest_api/{type}/get_fields` filter for all objects where `type` is `option` - as per the REST route in your question.

Here's a sample piece of code using the `acf/rest_api/{type}/get_fields` (found [here](https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api#filters)):

```php
function options_fields_filter( $data, $request ) {
   // here's where you'd mutate `$data` 

   return $data;
}

add_filter( 'acf/rest_api/option/get_fields', 'option_fields_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Hope this helps. If you want to tap into more specified filters per other "types," such as particular post types, take a deeper look into the REST API controllers located [here](https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api/tree/master/v3/lib/endpoints).

Comment: Thanks for this...is there any way to know what the structure of $data looks like without having to log it out first? I'm working a little blind at the moment. Each change requires a deploy that takes a few minutes (due to the way our setup is).

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo I don't think you can know the structure of what gets sent via the filter without doing further Local testing and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the filters to work.
However, using the `?p=` parameter along with the `post.ID`  you can redirect to the post.

I end up solving the issue for the link this way:

```
// JSX/React
<a href={`/?p=${ post.ID }`}>
   { post.post_title }
</a>
```